# Is there a way to delete an android or an ios app from a Firebase project using firebase admin sdk's ProjectManagement service?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

Firebase admin sdk for node JS has a ProjectManagement service which provides createAndroidApp and createIosApp methods for creating applications in a project. I was wondering if firebase admin sdk also provide methods for deleting these Android and Ios applications instead?

Or if none, then may be some other alternatives like firebase REST apis or some workaround for this?

Comment: Just a note, as of today (Feb 03, 2021) even these createApp APIs are beta features.
Even I am waiting for management apis.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same feature in the SDK for Python. As far as I know there's no way to delete an Android or iOS app. Unfortunately you have to manually delete them in the Firebase Console.

Maybe we can request this feature on Firebase GitHub repos:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues